# Netrw discards changes without asking

Tags: netrw

When I

1. Execute `vim A` command from shell
2. Edit the file `A` in some way (now `&modified == 1`)
3. Execute `:Lexplore` <sup>†1</sup> to enable the side pane of netrw
4. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> on an arbitary file `B`

, the file `B` is opened in the window in which `A` was opened **without** any prompt and, as a result, the modification to `A` is totally lost.

Is this an expected behavior? How can I get along with this buggy behavior?

<sub>†1: Edit: it turns out the problem is not specific to `:Lexplore` command. Netrw opened via `:Explore` or `:e` also shows the behavior.</sub>

---

**Current Status**

I suspect the behavior is unexpected (i.e. a bug). I'm debugging `netrw` according to the instructions found in `:help netrw` and have located the cause; `e!` is called in `autoload/netrw.vim`. Just replacing two `e!` with `e` solved the discarding behavior. But I still have to keep analyzing the code to know what kind of side effects will happen if `e!` is replaced with `e` and the operation fails due to `&modified == 1`.

---

**.vimrc**

Now I'm using a minimal `.vimrc` which has only the following two lines.

```
set nocp
filetype plugin on
```

---

**Environments**

I could reproduce the problem under multiple environments.

Comment: I can reproduce it with `:Lexplore` and it discards the changes in `A` when I open `B`. I upgraded to latest netrw from Dr. Chip's website (netrw v170c from March 30, 2020) and I can still reproduce it. Where is the `e!` you said causes it? Which function?

Comment: @filbranden See my GitHub [repository](https://github.com/your-diary/netrw_avoid_discarding_modified_buffer). Though I'm still writing `README.md`, the patch should work.

Comment: You might want to report it upstream. See Dr. Chip's page here: http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/index.html You'll probably have to send him an email, you can find his address at the top of the `:help netrw` page (remove the NOSPAM letters from the address there...)

Comment: @filbranden The patch was finally adopted in version `170f`. Again, thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Awesome!!! Thanks for following up on it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the behavior is a bug. Here's the patch to fix it.

```
--- netrw_before.vim    2020-04-30 13:12:10.225394138 +0900
+++ netrw.vim   2020-04-30 13:03:50.746727412 +0900
@@ -4899,9 +4899,19 @@
      " some like c-^ to return to the last edited file
      " others like c-^ to return to the netrw buffer
      if exists("g:netrw_altfile") && g:netrw_altfile
-      exe "NetrwKeepj keepalt e! ".fnameescape(dirname)
+      try
+       exe "NetrwKeepj keepalt e ".fnameescape(dirname)
+      catch
+       echoerr "No write since last change"
+       let __local_file_opening_error = 1
+      endtry
      else
-      exe "NetrwKeepj e! ".fnameescape(dirname)
+      try
+       exe "NetrwKeepj e ".fnameescape(dirname)
+      catch
+       echoerr "No write since last change"
+       let __local_file_opening_error = 1
+      endtry
      endif
 "     call Decho("edit-a-file: after e! ".dirname.": hidden=".&hidden." bufhidden<".&bufhidden."> mod=".&mod,'~'.expand("<slnum>"))
      call s:NetrwCursor()
@@ -4912,7 +4922,9 @@
     else
 "     call Decho("edit-a-file: remote file: NetrwBrowse will edit it",'~'.expand("<slnum>"))
     endif
-    let dolockout= 1
+    if !exists("__local_file_opening_error")
+     let dolockout= 1
+    endif

     " handle g:Netrw_funcref -- call external-to-netrw functions
     "   This code will handle g:Netrw_funcref as an individual function reference
```

Note, however, the patch is written for me and **not tested very well** (at least by me).

See [my GitHub repository](https://github.com/your-diary/netrw_avoid_discarding_modified_buffer) to get the latest version of the patch and detailed explanations about the cause, the algorithm of the patch, etc.

<del>I've already sent an e-mail about this bug to the author of `netrw`. I hope it will be fixed soon.</del>

**Update:** The patch has been adopted in `netrw 170f (April 30, 2020)`. However, I suspect it will take long for the version of `netrw` to be included in the upstream of `vim`. Till the day, if you'd like to remove the bug, manually download the plugin from the [official](http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/index.html#NETRW) and install it.